# recommendations for deploying a slack/bolt app to the cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, google-cloud-platform, slack, heroku

I've been trying to deploy my slack/bolt app, which works fine on Glitch, to AWS Lambda. Since we already use AWS, it seemed an obvious choice from the [list provided on Slack.com](https://api.slack.com/docs/hosting).

I was able to get a sample app up and running (from this [demo here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgFVzBNgidQ), but getting my own app, which uses the Bolt framework in all its asynchronicity, is proving elusive.

Has anybody out there successfully deployed a slack/bolt app to a cloud platform? Perhaps there's one better suited for this type of app.